# Vertx Microservices Architecture

Tags: vert.x

we are starting a new microservices project using vertx + spring.

We plan to start with this architecture:

1. vertx-commons: a project containing all vertx libraries
2. vertx-rest-server: a single http server that would handle all request and delegate to other microservices thru event bus
3. vertx-microservice-n: will process request coming from the rest server by listening to the eventbus (contains business logic and persistence layers).
   Other microservices will use this template.

Is this a recommended approach?

Comment: Why do you need Spring at all?

Comment: I will be using Spring inside the microservice for persistence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need Spring for persistence. Rather, you can use any of the DBMS or NoSQL component libraries of Vertx (Ex., vertx-redis-client) or write your own. Vert.x is a lightweight, embeddable, un-opinionated library with very nice extensibility. Vert.x by itself is sufficient to build your custom stack.

If you still look out for a framework based on Vert.x-3.x, you can refer to https://github.com/swisspush/gateleen

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does the gateleen project has any document? I cant find the document. What a pity

Comment: If you are looking for recent projects having mainstream focus than Gateleen, I would suggest https://quarkus.io/ but, it's more oriented towards Kubernetes. If you are not very particular about Vert.x now, https://micronaut.io/ also has sufficient focus and docs coverage.

Comment: Recent updates to Vert.x based frameworks. Unfortunately gateleen is not actively maintained. It is better to use https://quarkus.io/ as it is actively supported by RedHat and has become one of the favourite microservices framework which uses Vert.x under the hood. Otherwise, one can just adopt the vanilla Vert.x stack itself.

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus is a microprofile framework, built upon Vert.x, and exposes Spring extensions like security, rest, etc.

This way you can have both.